# Connection open error while calling the sub functions

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

This is the flow of my program..

```
Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdUpdate.Click
     ..
    ....

     Call comboRefresh()        ------>
     cmdNext.Text = "Add New"
     cmdEdit.Text = "Edit"
     cmdUpdate.Enabled = False
End Sub


Private Sub comboRefresh()

    ------> ....

    da.Fill(ds, "Vendor_Machine")

        cmbSn_no.ValueMember = "sr_no"
        cmbSn_no.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)  --
        cmbSn_no.SelectedIndex = 0

       ....
End Sub

Private Sub cmbSn_no_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbSn_no.SelectedIndexChanged

  ----->       cnnOLEDB.Open()
   ...
         Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = comm_SelVen.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read = True Then
        cmbSn_no.Text = dr("sr_no")
        cmbChal_no.Text = dr("chaln_no") ----->
    End If
    cnnOLEDB.Close()

End Sub

 Private Sub cmbChal_no_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbChal_no.SelectedIndexChanged
  ---->     cnnOLEDB.Open()
    ...
     cnnOLEDB.Close()

End Sub
```

Here It says problem “Connection already open...”and halts execution...  Even i  can’t comment the line `--->  cnnOLEDB.Open()` in the last sub function as I have to call `cmbChal_no_SelectedIndexChanged` alone also.. if I comment it give error that

> Connection is closed, needs to be open to execute DataReader

Please suggest me what to do...Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep a global object for your connection. Just build one everytime you require it and encapsulate the logic of creating, using and disposing through the Using Statement

```
Using cnnOLEDB = New OleDbConnection(connectionstring)
Using comm = new OleDbCommand(queryText, cnnOLEDB)
    cnnOLEDB.Open()
    ...
    Using dr = comm_SelVen.ExecuteReader
    If dr.Read = True Then
        cmbSn_no.Text = dr("sr_no")
        cmbChal_no.Text = dr("chaln_no") ----->
    End If
End Using
```

In this way your connection will be automatically closed when the flow exits from the Using statement and any resource used will be released through the Dispose also called automatically.
This happens also if for whatever reason you get an exception when the connection is still open

Probably, your connection is open because a previous run of your code has encountered an exception or you have forget to call Close somewhere on the global object cnnOLEDB

**EDIT**
Looking at your comment below, and whilst I don't like it, there is the possibility to test the property [ConnectionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.connectionstate.aspx) to avoid to reopen the connection if it is already opened

```
If cnnOLEDB.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
     cnnOLEDB.Open()
End If
```

Comment: @steve...Thanks a lot... but the problem still exist. and i hv not forgot to close the connection, it jumps to another function while it's open and hence it shows the error....

Comment: I was using one connection object for each class.. I cant create connection object for each function as there are many functions in a class..it will have lots of redundant code.... i hv changed as u said bt still same error is there...

Comment: Added a test on the ConnectionState

Comment: Thank you very much... @Steve I am really Sorry for that... I really like your answer but there were some problems with my editing so i couldn't use..but ur answer is very useful.. Thank for that..

Comment: can you Please help me with a new post , that I have posted a few mins back. Title is "Not able to search for a entry with duplicate values..."